# Bash beeline alias

Tags: bash, hiveql, beeline

I use beeline from the command line quite a lot, so I would like to create a bash alias for the beeline command that takes care of all the boilerplate for me and does some argument parsing and things. Specifically, one thing I would like to do is create a `showtables` command which takes a single argument, the name of a database, and invokes the beeline command with the boiler plate and passes the -e argument along with the appropriate SQL, i.e. - `showtables db1` should invoke `/usr/bin/beeline -u $config -e "SHOW TABLES IN db1"`. My source file looks like this :

```
/usr/bin/beeline --showHeader=False --outputformat=tsv2 -u $config -e \"SHOW TABLES IN $1\"
```

but the output is

```
...
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:4 cannot recognize input near 'SHOW' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in ddl statement (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'TABLES' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'IN' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'db1' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' (state=42000,code=40000)
...
```

I've verified that just doing

```
/usr/bin/beeline --showHeader=False --outputformat=tsv2 -u $config -e "SHOW TABLES IN db1"
```

works as expected. I don't understand why my executable isn't working though.

Comment: Why are you making the quotes literal instead of syntactic? That is to say, what's the _point_ of using `\"SHOW TABLES IN db1\"` instead of `"SHOW TABLES IN db1"` in this code?

Comment: (btw, what does this have to do with aliases at all? I don't see an alias definition anywhere in your question).

Comment: (also, `-u $config` is generally a bad idea for other reasons -- if you want to pass the configuration as a single word it should be `-u "$config"` instead; if the configuration can be multiple words, it should be defined as an array instead of a string, and expanded as `-u "${config[@]}"`; [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) goes into details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslashes before your quotes make them behave like regular characters from the perspective of parsing, and not like quotes anymore. Thus, when you put backslashes in front of the quotes, `SHOW TABLES IN db1` is no longer a string, but is four separate strings: `"SHOW`, `TABLES`, `IN`, and `db1"`.

These words are not valid queries when run on their own -- hence your error. Take out the backslashes and the issue goes away.